# making new dictionary with less values

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

```
names = {"Pietro Gemman": [191, 80],
         "Joshua Gein": [180, 71], 
         "Sally Lowe": [168, 62], 
         "Katie Howard": [164, 56],  
         "Lucas Hoe": [184, 62], 
         "Anderi Stark": [176, 81], 
         "Hannah Wu": [156, 48]}

first_names = {}
```

Hi, I want to use a `for` loop to make a new dictionary named `first_names` with keys of the first name of the people and their values as height. The dictionary `names` shows the name, height and weight of each person. How can I extract only the first name as a key and height as a value?

Comment: How do you want to handle the case where two items share the same first name? Also what about people who only have 1 name, like Cher?

Comment: I'm just a beginner level for python, so not pretty sure my answer is correct but for the same name we could probably use the if else statement. Also for the one name I think we can just use the 1 name instead..

Comment: Sorry but the first part didn’t make any sense to me

Comment: apart from that, I did note the “only the first name” mentioned in the post, so i would assume overwriting first names wouldn’t be an issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, where you loop through the dictionary and extract the information you want:

```
names = {
    "Pietro Gemman": [191, 80],
    "Joshua Gein": [180, 71],
    "Sally Lowe": [168, 62],
    "Katie Howard": [164, 56],
    "Lucas Hoe": [184, 62],
    "Anderi Stark": [176, 81],
    "Hannah Wu": [156, 48],
}

first_names = {key.split()[0]: value[0] for key, value in names.items()}

print(first_names)
```

---

Ouput:

```
{
    "Pietro": 191,
    "Joshua": 180,
    "Sally": 168,
    "Katie": 164,
    "Lucas": 184,
    "Anderi": 176,
    "Hannah": 156,
}
```

Comment: A potential issue with this or a similar solution is, if two or more persons have the same first names the values will be overwritten by the last of those names in the dictionary.

Comment: True, I'm not sure how to avoid that if op wants only first names. Any ideas?

Comment: Suppose we need to hear from [@Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15783880/jasmine) to answer [@Haleemur Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2570261/haleemur-ali)'s question